# Configure Web.Config (ASP.NET) to redirect web crawlers to another page

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I have a website using AngularJS running in an IIS web server. Since all the site's information is being requested via AJAX, social media crawlers are unable to parse that data. So, to prevent social media from showing empty expressions, for example: {{helloWorld}}, I'm trying to redirect some social media crawlers to a specific section in my web application that can prerender the page for the social media crawlers.

I've done this with success using an Apache .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit|Facebot|Twitterbot)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.com/prerender?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

What i would like to know is how can i accomplish the same thing using IIS. Basically i would like configure a Web.Config file with the equivalent rewrite rule as above.
Importante, in the script above i'm using the [P] flag to informe Apache to access the prerender page without the crawler knowing that a redirection has occured.

Any ideas on how i can do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666580/translating-apache-rewrite-rules-to-iis-web-config <- I hope it wll help you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue.

To simply rewrite the URL to another page in the same domain, URL Rewrite must be enabled in IIS. In order to rewrite to another domain you not only need URL Rewrite, but Application Request Routing enabled in the server as well (reverse proxy).

Then just use the following example rule in web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteTest" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="%{HTTP_USER_AGENT" pattern="(facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Facebot|Twitterbot/[0-9])" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hope this helps.